# How to optimize division by 100?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, optimization

I have a piece of code running into an loop, with a division by 100, which is reducing a little my fps count.

In majority of cases, is a **int/uint** type being divided by 100, resulting in a simple **Number**.

I just want to know any way to optimize that.

EDIT:
Little benchmark with the *@scriptocalypse* suggestion - multiplying for 0.01:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;

for(var k:Number = 20; k > 0; k--)
{
    var a:int = getTimer();

    var o:Number = 100;
    var p:Number;
    for(var i:Number = 100000000; i > 0; i--)
    {
        p = o * 0.01;  // took 423~510   <--------------
        //p = o / 100;  // took 713~768   <--------------
    }

    var b:int = getTimer();

    trace( b - a);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what it is you're doing?  There is approximately a 100% chance that improving the way you're doing whatever you're doing will result in a much, much better improvement than changing a single division operation.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I corrected all other problems that could be a problem. The game is pratically done, I just want improve some critical pieces of code that can be a **little** slower in some devices.

Comment: But more information will help us help you optimize.  For instance, what are you doing with these numbers after you do the division - adding them together?  It may be faster to add them all first, then divide.  Or are you dividing every entry in an array?  You may be able to parallelize that, or even better, offset the task to the GPU *(I don't know enough about Actionscript to know for sure)*.  Or perhaps we could suggest an alternate algorithm to achieve what you want *without* the millions of divisions.  But we can't do any of that without knowing what it is you're doing first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that it's not the division that's causing the bulk of your issues, as even slow math operations should be relatively fast compared to other operations.

While this:

```
x * 0.01;
```

should theoretically be faster than

```
x / 100;
```

I still suspect that it won't make much difference.  What else are you doing in your loop?

Comment: That really made a little, but noticeable improvement. How about bit shifting? Maybe it can improve more?

Comment: It increased speed by 30% - that's not "little".

Comment: @weltraumpirat, It's a little improvement in a real project. That benchmark is a far unreal case, done just for testing purposes - just to prove that multiplication is faster than division. In my project, the iteration isn't that big as 100 millions.

Comment: @MarceloAssis It still increases speed by 30% - the 100 million iterations just make the numbers measurable.

Comment: @Marcelo Assis I'm glad this was at least a measurable help, but are you sure there's nothing more you can do to economize your code?  Is there a way to reduce the number of math operations you have to perform?  Is there a way to intelligently group comparisons?  Not repeat comparisons? Are you constantly accessing sprite properties like x / y / rotation (which have implicit get/set functions) rather than storing your values locally and assigning only once?  Are you storing your object references in function-scoped variables, or using foo.bar.moo() style access?

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly, the right answer is **don't**. Programmers should write code that is clear to read, compilers should optimize.

Comment: Are you suggesting that programmers should not optimize their code because it might be harder to read? That is asinine.

Comment: @ilollar Not necessarily.  Optimizations may be in order if the performance impact is such that it significantly damages the user experience.  Otherwise readability should always come first - it is what makes code *maintainable*. If your code is very fast, but no other programmer, not even yourself, can come back after a month and understand what it's doing, it can become a very expensive "optimization" very quickly.  A couple of milliseconds delay, on the other hand, will almost always go unnoticed.

Comment: @Hbcdev I +1ed for the second part. However, programmers who know how to write optimized *and* readable code will almost always find ways to encapsulate what needs to be optimized, and still keep all the rest nice and readable.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I'm not advocating for "unreadably optimized code." After all, removing all white-space and reducing everything to one line could technically be called "optimizing," though it would be a ridiculous thing to do. However, the OP is asking about mathematical optimizations, and some operations that are less readable (like bit-wise or RegEx), may leave code less readable but the optimization benefits are still worthwhile.

Comment: @ilollar I wasn't talking about white space either.  In most cases, splitting your functions into smaller parts, separating concerns, declaring explanatory variables, providing longer method and variable names, etc.etc. will lead to great improvements in readability that greatly outweigh the performance benefits gained by "optimizing" the code.

Comment: @weltraumpirat My apologies, but are we talking about the same thing here? The OP is asking for how to do low-level math optimization to speed up the event loop and runtime of his app. I'm HUGE on code organization and readability, but this particular answer that we're commenting on makes it sound like code-speed optimizations shouldn't be bothered with by the programmer, and I think that is ridiculous. As mentioned before, just because bit-wise and RegEx is hard to read doesn't mean that they are better not used.

Comment: @ilollar Obviously, we are ;)  I'm not against optimizations - just against overdoing them.

Comment: Sirs @weltraumpirat & ilollar I think even if the needed(not desired) optimization turns some part of the code unreadable, the programmer can just add comments to explain why and what the next lines are doing. In projects with a lot of people working on, I even have the habit of placing links explaining why I did some not popular code snippets - like bit shifting.

Comment: @MarceloAssis Using comments instead of well-written code is a big no-no, links or no links.  Clean code speaks for itself.

Comment: @weltraumpirat, I think I was misunderstood. Try reading again my last post - I'm talking about REALLY NEEDED cases of optimization, it's not about make ugly commented code in everyday programming. I gave bit shifting as example, I explain why I'm using it and give links to my unexperienced teamates understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

You asked in a comment: *"How about bit shifting? Maybe it can improve more?"*

There's no bitwise operation you can use to divide by 100, you can use bit shifting to divide only by powers of 2 (2,4,8,16...).

[Here's](http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/2010/08/bitwise-operations-in-actionscript-3/) a good post about that.